# Spark SQL not able to alter views

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera-cdh

From my Scala Spark code I try to create a view if it doesn't exist and then later try to alter this view.

However this throws an exception.

> Can not create a Path from a null string

I proceeded to try on the spark shell and saw that its' the same story there:

```
sqlContext.sql("create view if not exists db.view_delme as select * from db.tbl")
sqlContext.sql("alter view db.view_delme as select * from db.tbl")
```

The part it fails on is the "alter view".

I don't fully understand why but it seems like it just hasn't been implemented properly. It seems to be based on the alter table code.

Comment: It seems a different thing, but possibly related: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-17180 -- Also, are you able to drop and create the view?

Comment: yes, drop and recreate works. But I don't want endusers looking at this view to experience any kind of downtime during queries. Won't I introduce that problem with drop/recreate?